LNK1104 when referencing a dynamic library
I have a c++ DLL project (call it MyDll) and a c++ console application in visual studio. I am trying to use this library in my console application but I'm getting a cannot open 'MyDll.lib'.
Here is what I did so far:

Added MyDll project as a reference in the console app.
Added MyDll.lib to the console's Linker > Input
Added MyDll's header path to the Additional Include Directories

Both projects have the same output directory $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\, and I made sure that the .lib and .dll files are being generated.
I was able to have a successful build by just copying MyDll.lib file to the console's .vcxproj directory.
This made me think that the console project is not using the output directory to look for library? How can I reference a dynamic library without having to have the .lib beforehand?

Did you add the folder of MyDll.lib to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories ?

No because the .lib does not exist until I build the solution. And it gets generated in the $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\ directory.

Maybe $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration) needs to be added to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories since even though that is an output folder it's not a folder the linker would normally look.

@drescherjm This would definitely work. But then what's the purpose of adding MyDll project as a reference to the console app. Because if I added $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\ to the Additional Library Directories, it will still work even if I remove MyDll from the references list.

"what's the purpose of adding MyDll project as a reference to the console app" - adding as a reference works for .NET project only as far as I know, not for native C++ ones.

I have never used references for native c or c++ code. When this feature was added to VS long ago it used to be a .NET only feature. Like @wohlstad mentioned not sure if that has changed. However with all of that said since 2008 I use CMake to generate almost all of my VS projects so I don't pay attention to these settings in the IDE much.

@drescherjm I'm pretty sure I've used the reference in c++ code. Though my usual use cases were referencing a static library project. This is the first time I try to reference a DLL project.

@wohlstad In the microsoft documentation they use reference with c++ code. Creating and using a library

@user24011790 I am not familiar with that option and don't know how well it works (always added the libraries "manually").

Could it be that a static lib the .lib is the artefact, while for a dynamic one it's just a  side effect, while the artefact is the .dll.. Inspect the linker command, and add the path manually. [SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer).

Have you set the project dependencies so that the lib is built before the console program

@cup Yes. When MyDll project is added as a reference, it gets built automatically before the console app.

The console app links to the .lib.  At runtime, this calls up the DLL.  You don't you need to reference the DLL unless you're doing a #import.
